# Why does Newtonsoft Replace function only replace the value if it is changed?

Tags: debugging, json.net

Take the following code:

```
JProperty toke = new JProperty("value", new JValue(50)); //toke.Value is 50
toke.Value.Replace(new JValue(20)); //toke.Value is 20
```

This works as expected. Now examine the following code:

```
JValue val0 = new JValue(50);
JProperty toke = new JProperty("value", val0); //toke.Value is 50
JValue val1 = new JValue(20);
toke.Value.Replace(val1); //toke.Value is 20
```

This also works as expected, but there is an important detail. val0 is no longer part of the toke's JSON tree, and val1 **is** part of the JSON tree; this means that val0 has no valid parent, while val1 does.

Now take this code.

```
JValue val0 = new JValue(50);
JProperty toke = new JProperty("value", val0); //toke.Value is 50
JValue val1 = new JValue(50);
toke.Value.Replace(val1); //toke.Value is 50
```

The behavior is different; val0 **is still** part of toke's JSON tree, and val1 is not. Now val0 has a valid parent, while val1 does not.

This is a critical distinction, and if you are using Newtonsoft JSON tree's to represent a structure, and storing JTokens as references into the tree, the way the references are structure can change based on the value being Replaced, which seems incorrect.

Is there any flaw with my reasoning? Or is behavior incorrect, as I believe it is?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a valid point: `Replace` should replace the token instance and set the parent properly even if the tokens have the same values.

This works as you would expect if the property value is a `JObject` and you replace it with an identical `JObject`:

```cs
JObject obj1 = JObject.Parse(@"{ ""foo"" : 1 }");
JProperty prop = new JProperty("bar", obj1);

JObject obj2 = JObject.Parse(@"{ ""foo"" : 1 }");
prop.Value.Replace(obj2);

Console.WriteLine("obj1 parent is " + 
        (ReferenceEquals(obj1.Parent, prop) ? "prop" : "not prop"));    // "not prop"
Console.WriteLine("obj2 parent is " + 
        (ReferenceEquals(obj2.Parent, prop) ? "prop" : "not prop"));    // "prop"
```

However, the code seems to have been deliberately written to work differently for `JValues`.  In the [source code](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json) we see that [`JToken.Replace()`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JToken.cs#L400) calls [`JContainer.ReplaceItem()`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JContainer.cs#L558), which in turn calls [`SetItem()`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JProperty.cs#L203).  In the `JProperty` class, `SetItem()` is implemented like this:

```cs
internal override void SetItem(int index, JToken item)
{
    if (index != 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    }

    if (IsTokenUnchanged(Value, item))
    {
        return;
    }

    if (Parent != null)
    {
        ((JObject)Parent).InternalPropertyChanging(this);
    }

    base.SetItem(0, item);

    if (Parent != null)
    {
        ((JObject)Parent).InternalPropertyChanged(this);
    }
}
```

You can see that it checks whether the value is "unchanged", and if so, it returns without doing anything.  If we look at the implementation of [`IsTokenUnchanged()`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JContainer.cs#L601) we see this:

```cs
internal static bool IsTokenUnchanged(JToken currentValue, JToken newValue)
{
    JValue v1 = currentValue as JValue;
    if (v1 != null)
    {
        // null will get turned into a JValue of type null
        if (v1.Type == JTokenType.Null && newValue == null)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return v1.Equals(newValue);
    }

    return false;
}
```

So, if the current token is a `JValue`, it checks whether it `Equals` the other token, otherwise the token is automatically considered to have changed.  And `Equals` for a `JValue` is of course based on whether the underlying primitives themselves are equal.

I cannot speak to the reasoning behind this implementation decision, but it seems to be worth [reporting an issue](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues) to the author.  The "correct" fix, I think, would be to make `SetItem` use `ReferenceEquals(Value, item)` instead of `IsTokenUnchanged(Value, item)`.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I've opened an issue [here](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1370), we'll see what comes of it.

Comment: Personally, I think this is the right behavior. A `JValue` represents a primitive value. Unfortunately, they couldn't be implemented with value semantics and have to be implemented using references. It should be wrong to expect that the references can be replaced when they represent the same value. Only the value matters, not the object that holds it.